# Ubuntu apparmor profiling

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

i have create a very simple profile for java, but i keep getting this error

```
kernel: [71175.816218] type=1503 audit(1283519910.092:8774):  
operation="mkdir" pid=23440 parent=1 
profile="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/bin/java" 
requested_mask="c::" denied_mask="c::" fsuid=1158 ouid=1158 name="/XFolder/"
```

i've set option to the profile to :

```
/XFolder/ c,
```

and even

/XFolder/ ixrw,

but i keep getting the error,  any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*which* profile?  Are you sure the application is using *that* version/source of java?

i.e. Perhaps the application in question is using a different version of sun-java... or one of the other flavors of java...

Comment: Sure of that version 100%, question is why i cannot create this 'c' tag

Comment: a "c" is actually a special character file... not really a file at all.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_special_file#Character_devices

Comment: Just looking closer... perhaps your config is wrong... it's trying to open a directory as a character file... name="/XFolder/" is a bit of a give away.